# Mapping with v:count in vim

Tags: vim, count, copy, mapping

I would like to map **<c-c>** to *copy* with some improvements over the well known  **<c-c>** shortcuts. If possible I would also like to use a generic mapping for it. I heard about *v:count* and I am wondering if a can use it here.

```
" Copy word under cursor 
inoremap <silent> <c-c> <esc>m`viw"+y``a
nnoremap <silent> <c-c>      m`viw"+y``

" Copy selection
vnoremap          <c-c> "+y

" Copy word under cursor in register [count]
inoremap <silent> 1<c-c> <esc>m`viw"1y``a
inoremap <silent> 2<c-c> <esc>m`viw"2y``a
inoremap <silent> 3<c-c> <esc>m`viw"3y``a
[...]
inoremap <silent> 7<c-c> <esc>m`viw"7y``a
inoremap <silent> 8<c-c> <esc>m`viw"8y``a
inoremap <silent> 9<c-c> <esc>m`viw"9y``a

nnoremap <silent> 1<c-c>      m`viw"1y``
nnoremap <silent> 2<c-c>      m`viw"2y``
nnoremap <silent> 3<c-c>      m`viw"3y``
[...]
nnoremap <silent> 8<c-c>      m`viw"8y``
nnoremap <silent> 9<c-c>      m`viw"9y``
```

The question is, can I use something like this and how can I do it ?

```
nnoremap <silent> <c-c>      m`viw"{v:count}y``
```

**Edit:**

With your help, I made this but I still have some issues with it. For instance, when I do 3 it will paste the content of the 'e' register 3 times. How to avoid that ?

```
nnoremap <expr> <C-c> MyYank()
inoremap <expr> <C-c> MyYank()
vnoremap <expr> <C-c> MyYank()

nnoremap <expr> <C-v> MyPaste('n')

" Not using numbered registers because they get rotated due to quote_number
" Instead. A indexed string is used to map <count> to a letter
let s:mapping = 'qwertzuiop'

fu! MyYank(...)    
    " Get the register to yank in
    let l:count = v:count > len(s:mapping) ? 0 : v:count
    let l:regs = l:count ? s:mapping[l:count - 1] : '+'

    " Action depends on the current mode
    let l:currentmode = a:0 > 0 ? a:1 : mode()
    if l:currentmode == 'n'
        return 'm`viw"' . l:regs . 'y``'
    elseif l:currentmode == 'i'
        return "\e" . 'm`viw"' . l:regs . 'y``a'
    elseif l:currentmode == 'v'
        return '"' . l:regs . 'y'
    endif
endfu

fu! MyPaste(...)   
    " Get the register to yank in
    let l:count = v:count > len(l:mapping) ? 0 : v:count
    let l:regs = l:count ? l:mapping[l:count - 1] : '+'

    " Action depends on the current mode
    let l:currentmode = a:0 > 0 ? a:1 : mode()
    if l:currentmode == 'n'
        return '"' . l:regs . 'P'
    elseif l:currentmode == 'i'
        return "\e" . 'm`viw"' . l:regs . 'y``a'
    elseif l:currentmode == 'v'
        return '"' . l:regs . 'y'
    endif
endfu
```

Comment: I would not recommend placing contents into the numbered registers. They get rotated and over written quite often. But you could probably do this with `exec` and `normal!`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that with a `:help :map-expr`:

```
" Copy word under cursor in register [count]
nnoremap <expr> <silent> <c-c>      'm`viw"' . (v:count ? v:count : '"') . 'y``'
```

However, like @FDinoff, I'd ask you to reconsider your approach of yanking to the numbered registers. If you rework your original `<C-c>` mapping (using `:map-expr` and `v:register`), you can already yank into arbitrary registers (by prefixing with `"{reg}`) and still default to the clipboard. And those `:imaps` with the count will cause a noticeable delay when entering numbers.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. However I didn't really understand the comment of @FDinoff. Why registers get rotated ? This means to me that I cannot do `"3y` because my third register can move by itself. What is the problem with numbered regiters ?

Comment: From `:help quote_number`: With each successive deletion or change, Vim shifts the previous contents
of register 1 into register 2, 2 into 3, and so forth, losing the previous
contents of register 9.