# Vim: Using v:count1 as argument of a mapping

Tags: vim, arguments, mapping

I have a mapping like below to move the cursor to the first column of input/update (the red-circled) area in a table. And I can type `w` or `ww` to get to the 2nd/3rd column if needed.

`noremap <s-F8> 0f\|ew`

It goes to the anchor `|` first, to the end of the green number, and moves to next word (can be a dot, a number or an expression) in the table as below.

[image: A table with 3 columns for data entry]

I wonder if I can use the count given in front of a normal-mode command to get to the 2nd or 3rd column directly, with a command `2<s-F8>` or `3<s-F8>`.

The following code doesn't work, though the `@=` helps separate the count from the `0` command.

`noremap <s-F8> @='0f\|ew'<cr>`

I studied the answer of Karkat in the post [Mapping with v:count in vim](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23881934/26702) and made this mapping:

```
noremap <expr> <s-F8> '0f\|e' . v:count1 . 'W'
```

But it doesn't move if a count is given. (It does move to column 1 if there is no count.)

What would be the correct way to use `v:count1` in such a mapping?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `:execute STRING` command to include the `v:count1` in the string:

```
noremap <silent> <s-F8> :<c-u>exe 'norm 0f\|e' . v:count1 . 'W'<cr>
```

Note: The CTRL-U is used to remove the range that Vim may insert.

Comment: Terrific! It works like a charm. I've tried hard with the `<expr>` approach but it remains tricky. The `:h map-expr` document doesn't help much.

Answer (score 1):

For your `<expr>` version, you need an `<esc>` to help cancel the COUNT (something like the CTRL-U does):

```
noremap <silent> <expr> <s-F8> '<esc>0f\|e' . v:count1 . 'W'
```

Comment: Wow! I was not aware that <esc> is required for this case! It looks the problem stems from it - something like "20f|" happened to be there (Vim's logic). Thank you so much!

Comment: This answer fixes my mapping. Both your answers are great! However, it looks I can not "accept" both here... To maintain the text flow, I keep your first answer accepted.

Comment: Never mind. To make the two versions easier to compare, I prepend a <silent> to this mapping.